# Formula in Excel: Matching Year and Date

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I have a date column and year column in this date column year must match with year column ..

like if date column have year 2019 then year column must be 2019 if 2017 then must be 2017 ..

```
  Date         Year 
    01-02-2019   2019
    02-09-2018     2018
   03-10-2017       2019
  04-11-2017        2018
```

so here i want to identify those who are not match date(year) and year column and highlight with yellow color . like last 2 records are incorrect so want to highlight with yellow color

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Through conditional formatting:

- Select `A2:B5`
- New conditional formatting rule through formula:

  ```
  =YEAR($A2)<>$B2
  ```
- Choose format and apply

[image]

---

To highlight the entire row:

- Select rows `2:5`
- Follow the same steps as above

[image]

Comment: HOW I HIGHLIGHT THE ROWS ?

Comment: @Mirror, no need for capslock ;). See edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

In column C =B1=Year(A1) then format with conditional formatting.